# Unable to import pandas on VScode and Atom IDE

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I am really frustrated right now and have tried so many workarounds all to no avail. I want to do some analysis on a csv file and I learnt that I would need to import pandas.

So I installed python version 3.10.5 and ran this code in terminal:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

This successfully installed pandas on terminal in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages

I ran this code on my Atom IDE and VScode too:
`import pandas as pd`

This was the error:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/augustine/Downloads/pythonscripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.python" Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/Users/augustine/Downloads/pythonscripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd 
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I saw on reddit that only python 3.9 supports pandas for now. I uninstalled version 3.10 and installed 3.9, on VS code, I changed the python interpreter to 3.9 version but it's the same thing happening. Please what am I supposed to do?

Comment: You mentioned in your content that pandas was successfully installed after installing Python 3.10, but why is the path python3.9? Please check carefully whether there are multiple versions of Python in your system.

Comment: Yes I saw multiple versions of python in my PC, and I have uninstalled 3.10, and changed the python interpreter on VS code to 3.9 version but it's the same issue happening

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice that every time you make a new project involving python, to change to that project's base directory and then run  `python -m venv venv` to set up a stable python environment there, when you use it you run `./venv/Scripts/activate`, and then all dependencies can be managed in a `requirements.txt` file.  The added bonus is if u do that, vscode will see it and then auto-suggest whether you want that to be the default interpreter for your project code.  If that doesnt happen, try the magic "ctrl + shift + p" and then start typing "python interpreter" -- an option will appear for you "Python: select interpreter" and then just use the one you've created in the venv (`./venv/Scripts/python.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the existence of multiple Python in your environment. Try to manually specify the python location in setting.json:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe",#your python path
```